# Application of the Archimedean Property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

**Prove if that $0<a<b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then there exist some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < a$ and $b < n $**

The question states to use the Archimedean Property; If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ where $a < b$, then there exist an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b <na$.

My guess is to begin with the result of the Archimedean Property ($b<na$) and try to manipulate that and arrive at $\frac1n$ and $b<n$ but I'm having trouble doing so, is this the right idea? Any guidance is appreciated !

Comment: You could apply the Archimedian Property to $b$ and $1$...

Comment: Show that an $n$ exists for each situation, and then consider the maximum of the two.

Answer (score 1):

I'll get you started. Using el_tenedor's comments: Consider $b$ and $1$. By the Archimedean Property, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $b<N$. Now consider $a$ and $1$. By the Archimedean property, there exists $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1<aM$, which implies the $\frac{1}{M}<a$. Now, what happens if you take the maximum of $\{M,N\}$?

Here, we've assumed that $a<1$ and $b>1$, by the way. That is also something you'll need to work around.

Comment: @J.Jones did you find this useful?